# PyBind11 'generic_type: type "" is already registered!' when importing two modules with the same enum

Tags: c++, python-3.x, pybind11

I'm importing two modules written in C++ using PyBind11 in my Python program. Both modules A & B export a enum with the same name. I'm importing both to do some testing and comparison.

Their code is like this:

Module A:

```cpp
PYBIND11_MODULE(module_A, m) {

    py::enum_<ENUM_NAME>(m, "ENUM_NAME")
        .value("ENUM_VAL1", ENUM_VAL1)
        .export_values();
```

Module B:

```cpp
PYBIND11_MODULE(module_B, m) {

    py::enum_<ENUM_NAME>(m, "ENUM_NAME")
        .value("ENUM_VAL2", ENUM_VAL2)
        .export_values();
```

When I import both of them with `__import__(module_X)` in Python I get this error:

```
generic_type: type "ENUM_NAME" is already registered!
```

Why does this happen? The enums are tied to the module right? Why would it matter if two modules have attributes with the same name?

I can of course just rename one, or just import one module at the time but I want to have the flexibility to have any name for any module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer have something wrong. You can mark your enum with Annotation `py::module_local` to export it locally.

See: [Example](https://github.com/shabbywu/python-memory-importer/blob/main/src/physfs.shim.cpp#L275)

```cpp
    py::enum_<PHYSFS_FileType>(m, "PHYSFS_FileType", py::module_local())
        .value("PHYSFS_FILETYPE_REGULAR", PHYSFS_FileType::PHYSFS_FILETYPE_REGULAR)
        .value("PHYSFS_FILETYPE_DIRECTORY", PHYSFS_FileType::PHYSFS_FILETYPE_DIRECTORY)
        .value("PHYSFS_FILETYPE_SYMLINK", PHYSFS_FileType::PHYSFS_FILETYPE_SYMLINK)
        .value("PHYSFS_FILETYPE_OTHER", PHYSFS_FileType::PHYSFS_FILETYPE_OTHER)
    ;
```

Furthermore See: [Document Module-local class bindings](https://github.com/shabbywu/python-memory-importer/blob/main/src/physfs.shim.cpp#L275).

Answer (score 1):

The error "`generic_type: type "ENUM_NAME" is already registered!`" occurs because `PyBind11` registers the enum type globally, even though it is defined within different modules. To avoid this issue, you can encapsulate the enums within a class or a struct.

Here's two approaches:

> 1: Encapsulate the enums within a class or struct

For example, in Module A:

```cpp
struct EnumWrapperA {
    enum ENUM_NAME {
        ENUM_VAL1
    };
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(module_A, m) {
    py::class_<EnumWrapperA>(m, "EnumWrapperA")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def_readwrite("ENUM_NAME", &EnumWrapperA::ENUM_NAME);
}
And in Module B:

struct EnumWrapperB {
    enum ENUM_NAME {
        ENUM_VAL2
    };
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(module_B, m) {
    py::class_<EnumWrapperB>(m, "EnumWrapperB")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def_readwrite("ENUM_NAME", &EnumWrapperB::ENUM_NAME);
}
```

***Pros***:

Allows you to have enums with the same name in different modules.

***Cons***:

Requires additional code to define the wrapper class or struct.

> 2: Combine the modules into a single module

Another approach is to combine the two modules into a single module, as shown in [connected pybind11 modules #1391](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1391). This way, you can avoid the name conflict altogether.

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

enum ENUM_NAME_A {
    ENUM_VAL1
};

enum ENUM_NAME_B {
    ENUM_VAL2
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(combined_module, m) {
    py::enum_<ENUM_NAME_A>(m, "ENUM_NAME_A")
        .value("ENUM_VAL1", ENUM_VAL1)
        .export_values();

    py::enum_<ENUM_NAME_B>(m, "ENUM_NAME_B")
        .value("ENUM_VAL2", ENUM_VAL2)
        .export_values();
}
```

***Pros***:

Avoids name conflict by having separate enum names in a single module.

***Cons***:

Requires combining the modules, which may not be desirable in some cases.

Comment: So for now it is not possible to have the same name in two separate modules without any of these changes?
I am actually creating a wrapper for a library so option one is not possible. I'll just have to import them one by one and move on to option 2.
Thanks so much for the fast and great reply.

Comment: yes, you're correct  it's currently not possible to have the same enum name in two separate modules without any changes, there's really isn't a more straightforward solution without modifying the code structure.